# a formula of fractional edge chromatic number

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Given a graph $G$, for a vertex subset $U$, let $t(U)=\frac{2|E(G[U])|}{|U|-1}$.

One (Theorem 4.2.1 of the book ["Fractional hypergraph coloring"](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/ers/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fgt.pdf)) claims that the  [fractional edge chromatic number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalEdgeChromaticNumber.html)
$$\chi_f'(G)=\max(\Delta(G), \max_{U\subseteq V(G):\text{$|U|$ is odd}}t(U)).$$

I am wondering why it is true? Any reference of the proof?

Comment: See the bit that says "**Proof** (of Theorem 4.2.1)."